# How to store data locally using Flash CS5?

Tags: flash-cs5

I am developing a simple application using Adobe Flash CS5, Can I store simple data locally when targeting iPad?

Would I need native extension to store local data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CS5 or CS5.5?

I haven't tried that myself but in any case you must be using AIR, and it looks like you could try using files or local SharedObject: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/saving_state_air_apps.html